# pattern for updating a datastore object

Tags: endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm wondering what the right pattern should be to update an existing datastore object using endpoints-proto-datastore.

For example, given a model like the one from your GDL videos:

```
class Task(EndpointsModel):
    detail = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    owner = ndb.StringProperty()
```

imagine we'd like to update the 'detail' of a Task.

I considered something like:

```
@Task.method(name='task.update',
             path='task/{id}',
             request_fields=('id', 'detail'))
def updateTask(self, task):
    pass
```

However, 'task' would presumably contain the previously-stored version of the object, and I'm not clear on how to access the 'new' detail variable with which to update the object and re-store it.

Put another way, I'd like to write something like this:

```
def updateTask(self, task_in_datastore, task_from_request):
    task_in_datastore.detail = task_from_request.detail
    task_in_datastore.put()
```

Is there a pattern for in-place updates of objects with endpoints-proto-datastore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/simple_get.html) for details on this

> The property `id` is one of five helper properties provided by default
>   to help you perform common operations like this (retrieving by ID). In
>   addition there is an `entityKey` property which provides a base64
>   encoded version of a datastore key and can be used in a similar
>   fashion as `id`...

This means that if you use the default `id` property your current object will be retrieved and then any updates from the request will replace those on the current object. Hence doing the most trivial:

```
@Task.method(name='task.update',
             path='task/{id}',
             request_fields=('id', 'detail'))
def updateTask(self, task):
    task.put()
    return task
```

will perform exactly what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Task is your model, you can easily update like this:

```
@Task.method(name='task.update',
         path='task/{id}',
         request_fields=('id', 'detail'))
def updateTask(self, task):
    # Task.get_by_id(task.id)
    Task.detail = task.detail
    Task.put()
    return task
```